# Creating a CSV file for excel with special character

Tags: php, excel, csv, utf-8

I have created a simple PHP script as a test. I want to have PHP save a csv from some data. This script works, but when I open it in Excel the special characters are gibberish.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Character Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<ul>
<?php
$spanishDept = array('Swimwear'=>'Trajes de baῆo','Boys Swimwear'=>'Trajes de baῆo','Girls Swimwear'=>'Trajes de baῆo','Kids Shoes'=>'Zapatos de niῆos',"Scarves"=>'Paῆoletas','Children\'s'=>'Niῆos','Coffee Mugs'=>'Tasas para café');

$list = '"Item","Spanish"'."\r";
foreach($spanishDept AS $english=>$spanish) {
        echo '<li>'.$english.': '.$spanish.'</li>';
        $list .= '"'.$english.'","'.$spanish."\"\r";
}
$fp = fopen('theEXCELlist.csv',"w+");
fwrite($fp,$list,strlen($list)+100);
?>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I can open it in NotePad++ or Dreamweaver and all is fine, but in Excel no good

Comment: You may need to do some character conversion before excel can handle it.

Comment: If you're writing csv, consider PHP's fputcsv() function rather than creating your own csv string

Comment: replace your \r Carriage Return with \n New Line

Comment: As much trouble as they generally cause, a byte order marker might actually help here as (one would hope) it will force Excel into UTF8 mode. You should certainly look at [`fputcsv()`](http://php.net/fputcsv) here though, it will make your life sooo much easier and your code less error-prone.

Comment: That's not a csv file you're building. it's an HTML file.

Comment: @MarcB I thought that but if you look harder you'll see it's not. It's a weird mix of logic though.

Comment: I appreciate the fputcsv() suggestion, but that has nothing to do with the problem. Excel opens the file just fine, but the special character are not correct. According to NotePad++ it has no BOM. It is not just an html it is also a csv file, the html was just to see the output

Comment: @Elliott What is was suggesting with the BOM is that you *put one in*, not remove it. It might help persuade Excel to treat the file as UTF8. I don't know.

Comment: I have opened it in NotePad++ and changed it to with and without BOM, but it is all the same.

Comment: Is your PHP file encoded in UTF8? Make sure it is and try again, it might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the solution to this problem lies in the "[Multibyte String Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php#50298)" section of the PHP manual.
In other words, it seems that the PHP output file should be an UTF-16 little endian encoded file (with BOM).
I don't know which version of Excel you're using, but [this post](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/dataexport/#section_6) may be useful.
Another approach could be to open Excel, insert the special characters, save as CSV and finally check how these characters are encoded in the output file.